# How to return a numpy array instead of a NoneType in applying a function to every row of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find the minimum non-zero pairwise distance for every row in my matrix (511x511). However, in the following code that I have written, I could either obtain the value for the first row using the return function or value for all the rows using the print function.

My code:

```
def allmatch():
    Match = pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(m1, metric='braycurtis')),columns=df.Location_Index.unique(), index=df.Location_Index.unique())
    X = Match.values
    for row in X:
        i = np.where(row==np.min(row[np.nonzero(row)]))
        return(row[i])

In[1]: allmatch()
Out[1]: array([0.00917431])
```

Or

```
    def allmatch():
        Match = pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(m1, metric='braycurtis')),columns=df.Location_Index.unique(), index=df.Location_Index.unique())
        X = Match.values
        for row in X:
            i = np.where(row==np.min(row[np.nonzero(row)]))
            print(row[i])

In[2]: allmatch()
Out[2]: [0.00917431]
        [0.03496503 0.03496503]
        [0.01098901]
        [0.00346021]
        [0.00471698]
        [0.00316456]
        [0.01123596]
        ...(with 504 more values)
```

While the first set of codes returns a numpy array, the second set of codes returns a NoneType. I will like to obtain the values in the second set in the form of a numpy array, are there any way to approach this? I realize that my code might not be the most efficient way to solve this problem and I will be grateful for any suggestions to improve it.

Comment: You need to create an array in the second function then and return it then, print always returns `None`

Comment: Pay close attention to where and how you `return` from the function.  Without a `return` statement, the function returns `None`.  And is the return from within the loop intentional?

Comment: How would I be able to create an array in the second function?